# JSON and a .rss file

Tags: android, json, rss

I'm pretty new to android development and I was wondering if I could get some input on what to do in my case. I'm trying to make a list of events that are going on at my school using the calendar that's on its website. The problem is, the only way I found to get to the JSON format is through the .rss which looks like this [link](http://carverhs.bcps.org/syndication/rss.aspx?serverid=3704999&userid=5&feed=portalcalendarevents&key=oOmZY4wrsUVTpHrsSjMyh%2Fh%2B6RzU%2BTL48gzt4atVjZcnzW8EBeCasOQ7QMAlvXX6993cCgazXTJ6v3I3OYgtKQ%3D%3D&portal_id=3705083&page_id=5278713&calendar_context_id=5278715&portlet_instance_id=220455&calendar_id=5278716&v=2.0)

I put it into myjson and got this error message and I have no idea what it means:
Parse error on line 1:

My goal is to be able to use JSON to create a list in a ListView on the app I'm making, but so far I'm completely lost as far as what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

JSON is entirely different from RSS.

Look into this tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm) or check out github, there's a ton of libraries that support RSS parsing such as [this](https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library) or [this](https://github.com/salendron/Simple-Rss2-Android)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorials Kony. One question though, how would I turn something like the list in the rss to a list in my ListView? I tried teaching myself JSON but since I don't need the JSON lists anymore I'm kind of lost.

Comment: You'll want to pull the RSS data into some kind of collection like a list and then display it as a listview. I found a tutorial [here](http://blog.nerdability.com/2013/03/tech-building-rss-reader-android-app.html) that shows just how to make an RSS feed using a library from github.

Just a note on that one though, he uses a `ListFragment` instead of a `ListView` but it should be pretty easy to adapt the code for what you want.

Comment: I've been trying to follow the tutorial that you've given me which is pretty clear, I just don't know how to use GitHub. I found the RSS reader on GitHub but is that a different project on its own? I'm trying to keep everything native on my project. When I follow the code that's on the tutorial I keep getting an error but I believe it's because I can't find the libraries that I need to download.

Comment: Oh I just figured out how to tag people @Kony2013.